# The inline css properties in the following code doesn't work

Tags: html, css, centering

```
<header>
    <b style="text-align:center;">Header</b>
</header>
```

The text comes in bolder but it fails to align center

Comment: give the `text-align:center` to the `header`

Comment: You can also add `display: block;` to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to set the `text-align:center` on the header tag for it to work.

```html
<header style="text-align:center;">
  <b>Header</b>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<header style="text-align:center;">
    <b>Header</b>
</header>
```

Edit: I guess am the third one to post the exact same answer :D

Answer (score 1):

`<b>` is an inline element and it wont support `text-align: center`. You may either make  as a block element by applying `display:block` or apply `text-align: center` to the `<header>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<header style="text-align:center;">
  <b>Header</b>
</header>
```

set the center tag in the top of text.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<center><b>Header</b></center>
```

You can try this without CSS:

**Header**

Comment: `center` is deprecated. You should avoid using it. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: you said without css, but as you can see in the <b> tag it has a style LOL!

Comment: where is that? :P